# Newbie CSS regarding inline-block alignment

Tags: html, css

I cannot see anything wrong with my code but unfortunately the below code does not line up. I know it has something to do with the font but beyond that i have no idea. I know i can do this with floats, but i want to know why inline-block is not working.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">

        body {
            font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
            font-size: 10px;
        }

        .label, .input {
            display: inline-block;
            height: 30px;
            width: 235px;
            background-color: E4E4E4;
            border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
            padding: 5px;
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="label">Client</div>
    <div class="input"><input type="text" name="client"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not relevant to your actual problem, but always add a doctype as the very first line, such as `<!DOCTYPE html>` to have consistent rendering between different browsers and to avoid IE completely screwing up your page.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `vertical-align: bottom;`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you missed a `#` when defining a background colour, but the main problem is:

Try messsing with the `vertical-align` property. Set it to `top`, `middle`, or `bottom` and see if any of those work for you.

Answer (score 1):

These folks are right, vertical-align is the issue:

```
    .label, .input {
        display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
        height: 30px;
        width: 235px;
        background-color: #E4E4E4;
        border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
        padding: 5px;
    }
```

Also, so you know, these inline elements are white-space sensitive, so if you don't want space between the elements, do this:

```
<div class="label">Client></div><div class="input"><input type="text" name="client"></div>
```